# Redux state not getting received as expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I'm using redux for the first time and something subtle is getting by me.

I have a container called Dashboard that displays two SimpleTabs. A simple tab is component that gets pressed and returns a number to its container for the item pressed. I can see actions being dispatched, event handler firing etc but the state being received in mapStateToProps never contains the item values. This might be why the render is never getting fired because the state is not changed.

Note: I've used the Ignite boilerplate as a starting point. It makes use of reduxsauce so the DashboardRedux.js may look a little unusual.

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import moment from 'moment'
import { Images, Colors, Metrics, ApplicationStyles } from '../Themes'
import SimpleTab from '../Components/SimpleTab'
import DashboardHeader from '../Components/DashboardHeader'
import DashboardActions from '../Redux/DashboardRedux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


export class Dashboard extends Component {
  //TODO make numbers into enums
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.updateTimeframe = this.updateTimeframe.bind(this)
    this.updateAnalysisView = this.updateAnalysisView.bind(this)
    const curTimeframe = 0
    const curAnalysisView = 0
    this.state = {curTimeframe, curAnalysisView}
  }

  // Event handler for timeframe tab
  updateTimeframe(newValue) {
    //newValue gets received as expected
    this.props.updateTimeframe(newValue)
  }

  // Event handler for analysisview tab
  updateAnalysisView(newValue) {
    this.props.updateAnalysisView(newValue)
  }

  getUpdateTime = () => {
    let s = moment().format("h:mm a")
    return s
  }

  // Takes us back to login
  openLoginScreen = () => {
    //TODO does  navigater have notion of <back>?
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
  }


  // For info on flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
  render () {
    let styles = ApplicationStyles.screen
    /*
    let localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          paddingBottom: Metrics.baseMargin
        },
        centered: {
          alignItems: 'center'
        }
      })

    console.log(styles)
    */

    return (
      //Problem: this.props.curTimeframe is always undefined
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

        <DashboardHeader updateTime={this.getUpdateTime()}></DashboardHeader>

        <View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}} >
          <SimpleTab
            onSelect={this.updateTimeframe}
            curTab={this.props.curTimeframe}
            tabNames={["TODAY", "1W", "1M", "3M", "6M"]}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{flex:1}} >
          <Text style={{color: Colors.snow}}>
            Analytical stuff for {this.props.curTimeframe} and {this.props.curAnalysisView}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{height:60, justifyContent: 'space-between'}} >
          <SimpleTab
            onSelect={this.updateAnalysisView}
            curTab={this.props.curAnalysisView}
            tabNames={["HOME", "DAYPART", "REC", "INGRED", "SETTINGS"]}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

    )}

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // Problem: state passed never contains curAnalysisView or curTimeframe
  return {
    curAnalysisView: state.curAnalysisView,
    curTimeframe: state.curTimeframe
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateTimeframe: newValue => dispatch(DashboardActions.updateTimeframe(newValue)),
    updateAnalysisView: newValue => dispatch(DashboardActions.updateAnalysisView(newValue))
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

**DashboardRedux.js**

```
    import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  updateTimeframe: ['newValue'],
  updateAnalysisView: ['newValue'],
})

export default Creators
export const DashboardTypes = Types

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  curTimeframe: 0,
  curAnalysisView: 0
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */
export const updateTimeframe = (state, {newValue}) => {
  //newValue gets passed as expected
  return state.merge({curTimeframe: newValue});
}

export const updateAnalysisView = (state, {newValue}) => {
  return state.merge({curAnalysisView: newValue});
}

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.UPDATE_TIMEFRAME]: updateTimeframe,
  [Types.UPDATE_ANALYSIS_VIEW]: updateAnalysisView
})
```

**SimpleTab.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { Colors, Metrics, Fonts, Images } from '../Themes/'
import styles from '../Themes/ApplicationStyles'

export default class SimpleTab extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onSelect: null,
    curTab: 0,
    tabNames: ["Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"]
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onSelect: PropTypes.func,
    curTab: PropTypes.number,
    tabNames: PropTypes.array
  }


  tabSelected = (tabNum) => {
    this.props.onSelect(tabNum);
  }

  renderTabBar = () => {
    let localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
          unselectedText: {
            marginTop: Metrics.baseMargin,
            marginHorizontal: Metrics.baseMargin,
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontFamily: Fonts.type.base,
            fontSize: Fonts.size.regular,
            color: Colors.snow
          },
          selectedText: {
            marginTop: Metrics.baseMargin,
            marginHorizontal: Metrics.baseMargin,
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontFamily: Fonts.type.base,
            fontSize: Fonts.size.regular,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: Colors.fire
          }
        })

    let result = []
    for (i=0; i<this.props.tabNames.length; i++) {
      let tabStyle = (i == this.props.curTab) ? localStyles.selectedText : localStyles.unselectedText
      result.push(
        <TouchableHighlight key={this.props.tabNames[i]} onPress={this.tabSelected.bind(this, i)}>
          <Text style={tabStyle}>{this.props.tabNames[i]}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    }
    return result
  }

  render () {
    console.log("rendering tab")

    return (
      <View flexDirection='row' style={styles.contentContainer}>
        {this.renderTabBar()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MapStateToProps receives the new state properties via reducers. Your MapStatetoProps in Dashboard.js should look like below to get the new values.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
// Problem: state passed never contains curAnalysisView or curTimeframe
//new state values should be accessed via reducers..
return {
    curAnalysisView: state.updateAnalysisView['curAnalysisView'],
    curTimeframe: state.updateTimeframe['curTimeframe']
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  state, when received here does not contain updateAnalysisView or updateTimeframe. I did find the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

the mapStateToProps should like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
const stateObj = state.toJS()
return {
    curAnalysisView: stateObj.curAnalysisView,
    curTimeframe: stateObj.curTimeframe
 }
}
```

the **.toJS()** function converts it from immutable object to JS object.

Also, the reducer should have a default case that just returns the current state for when there is no action passed.

Comment: It's saying state.toJS() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to specify the "dashboard" branch of the state tree like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    curAnalysisView: state.dashboard.curAnalysisView,
    curTimeframe: state.dashboard.curTimeframe
  }
}
```